# Is it common for app icons to not fill the entire area in xcode? (image included)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm watching a tutorial, and this guys icons look like this:

[image]

Mine look this this:

[image]

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The icon does show up correctly for the app, so that's good. But I'm still concerned about the visual discrepancy between my screen and my sensei's screen.

It's hard to see, but his fill up the entire "empty image" area, where mine are super small.

Comment: The 2x for the 20pt icon needs to be 40x40px and the 3x for the 20pt icon needs to be 60x60px. Is that the case? Multiply the 1x/2x/3x times the pt size to get the needs number of pixels for the image.

Comment: I'm nearly 100% I followed your logic which gave the above image but I will quadruple check.

Comment: Try to use the example icon in your project and vice versa. Check their size again as rmaddy said

Comment: Yeah, I'd say your icons are too small.  20 pts means 20 logical units, which should be 40 px for @2x, etc.

Comment: Yeah, it is a 40X40 icon. That's all correct. My only guess at this point is maybe my original icons are poorly formatted or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, this had to do with the PNG's resolution. I had 300, his was 96.